# Proper resize of image

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, image-preprocessing

I capture an image using android camera and was saved as Bitmap.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_CODE);
if(requestCode == CAMERA_CODE){
        Bundle b = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)b.get("data");
//I changed the bitmap from immutable to mutable somewhere here
mutableBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mutableBitmap, widthOfscreen, heightOfScreen, false);
        cropView.setBitmap(mutableBitmap);
    }
```

The problem is that the bitmap is small and I want something bigger. It is just that the result of my code was that there were some pixelated areas or an instinct that the result was not matched from the original image.